# C# DataGridView Colspan

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, excel, datagridview

I want to dynamically create a excel-like table with `datagridview`, but I want to have the option to set `colspan` to some columns.

The idea is just to display data, the user will not type anything, but it should be in table/spreadsheet look. If I cannot have `datagridview` with `colspan` is there any other type of table-like tool which has a `colspan`?

I other hand the columns will be created *dynamically* from database query result.

I'm using windows forms.

Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing. I'm new to .NET and I dont know what are the options. Datagridview is looking good for my purposes, but doesnt have colspan, which makes it unusable for me.

Comment: Telerik's radcontrols are pretty good - they have a gridview which has many options

Comment: Isn't radcontrols only for ASP? I'm writing a windows forms application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might take a look at the [TableLayoutPanel Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel.aspx), which has a [TableLayoutPanel.SetColumnSpan Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.setcolumnspan.aspx).

Here's a code sample, which spans the one of the text boxes on 2 columns:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Id");
dt.Columns.Add("Value1");
dt.Columns.Add("Value2");

dt.Rows.Add(1, "aa", "xx");
dt.Rows.Add(2, "bb","yy");
dt.Rows.Add(3, "cc", "zz");
tableLayoutPanel1.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 4;
tableLayoutPanel1.AutoSize = true;
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    var l = new Label();
    l.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    l.Text = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(l, i, 0);
}
var emptyLabel = new Label();
emptyLabel.Text = "Empty label";
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(emptyLabel, 4, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.Length; j++)
    {
        var tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Multiline = true;
        tb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        tb.Text = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(tb, j, i+1);
        if (i == 1 && j == 2)
            tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumnSpan(tb, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm thinking about. But it seems to me that if I have a lot of columns and rows to fill it renders really slow. :/

Comment: This is just a workaround which can't replace the role of a `DataGridView`.