# Is there a way to have a WinForms DataGridView with a column displaying multiple values from a record

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I am trying to display 2 or 3 values from a record into a single cell row of a DataGridView. Below is a class representing a record to databind to:

```
Class Book
{
  public int BookId {get;set;}
  public string Title {get;set;}
  public string Publisher {get;set}
  public string Author {get;set}
  public Date CopyrightDate {get;set}
  public byte[] BookCoverImage {get;set}
}
```

Id like to have a grid that looks like the following:

[image]

I am only interested in finding out how to create the second column titled Summary Information.  I've been wondering if there is a way to have the information in the Summary Column displayed from a data bound source.  For now I am displaying the information each in their own column but would like multiple values in single cell like the sample picture shows.  If this can be done in a WinForms DataGridView (or maybe there is another control I should be using?) can someone please provide information or a link to information on how this can be done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [How to Merge DataGridView Cell in Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774966/how-to-merge-datagridview-cell-in-winforms) and [C# DataGridView Colspan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524739/c-sharp-datagridview-colspan) might help you.

Comment: Robert, I have added an answer which should solve your concern. Let me know if you want something else to be done too!

Comment: You also may want to look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228710/how-can-i-create-a-footer-for-cell-in-datagridview/30234696#30234696)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose you have `dataGridView1` and you want to display data as you have shown in image of question. You can do something like below.

here we have used "\n" to add new lines in cell's value and `DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode` will take care of putting data in new line properly.

you would need to set columns re-sizable as per content.

```
List<Book> bookList = new List<Book>();
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    //for simplicity of solution, i have used cover as string not image,
    // you can perform same logic with cover as image too.
    bookList.Add(new Book(i, "title" + i, "publisher" + i, "auther" + i, "cover" + i));
}

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ColBook");
dt.Columns.Add("ColData");

foreach(Book book in bookList)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["ColBook"] = book.BookCoverImage;
    dr["ColData"] = "Title:"+book.Title + "\nPublisher:" + book.Publisher + "\nAuthor:" + book.Author;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

Comment: This option may work for now. When the data is returned from the repository I'll have the service layer transform the records during the building of the BindingList<Book> step to have line feeds into a new class property (SummaryInfo). This will be a DTO so the list is now BindingList<BookDto> fed into BindingSource.DataSource which I assign to the grid DataSource property. I was hoping there was a way to somehow point a user control into the cell or something built in for this. I've noticed Telerik has a ListControl that seems to do something like this also.

Comment: @Robertcode in your preferred way too, if your `DTO` can expose a property which is created as combined (something like `...Title + "\nPublisher:" + ...`) , it will automatically be reflated in `DataSource` of grid view right ? It should work then. try It out

Comment: using line feeds works along with the DataGridView settings you listed above.  This will do for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use either of the following solutions:

- Add a readonly summary property to the class and use a bound column.
- Use `CellFormatting` event to provide value for an unbound column.
- Use `CellPainting` event to custom draw the content of a bound or unbound cell.
- Use [`DataRepeater`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/windows-forms/introduction-to-the-datarepeater-control-visual-studio) control.

**Option 1 - Adding Summary Property**

You can add a new `Summary` property containing the information which you want to show in cell:

```
Class Book
{
    // rest of properties ...
    public string Summary
    {
        get 
        {
            return
                $"Title: {this.Title}\n" +
                $"Author: {this.Author}\n" +
                $"Copyright Date: {this.CopyrightDate}";
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can simply use a bound column to show data in the `DataGridView`.

*Note 1:* If the model is auto generated, you can put the new property in a partial class.

*Note 2:* In case of using `DataTable` you can simply create a formula column by setting expression for the column.

**Option 2 - Cell Formatting**

You can add an unbound column and simply provide the value of the cell at runtime in `CellFormatting` event of the `DataGridView` control:

```
private void dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    var dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex == dgv.NewRowIndex)
        return;
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 /*The column index which you want to format*/)
    {
        var book = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as Book;
        if (book != null)
            e.Value =
                $"Title: {book.Title}\n" +
                $"Author: {book.Author}\n" +
                $"Copyright Date: {book.CopyrightDate}";
    }
}
```

**Option 3 - Using `CellPaintig` event to custom draw cell**

You can see an example of painting cell content with different fonts in this post: [How can I create a footer for cell in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30234696/3110834).

**Option 4 - Using `DataRepeater` Control**

You can use a [`DataRepeater`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488280.aspx) control.

> The Visual Basic Power Packs
>   [`DataRepeater`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.datarepeater.aspx)
>   control is a scrollable. container for controls that display repeated
>   data, for example, rows in a database table. It can be used as an
>   alternative to the `DataGridView` control when you need more control
>   over the layout of the data. The `DataRepeater` "repeats" a group of
>   related controls by creating multiple instances in a scrolling view.
>   This enables users to view several records at the same time.